# Undefined method - attribute is NULL after submitting form (Rails 3.2.13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

ERROR:

`undefined method 'function_id' for #<Person:0xa004934>`

There is a trial management system. So far a user has been able to create new participants. Now the user should be able to create new persons, too. That person is meant to be also participant of a trial.

We have a form to create a new person. After hitting `create person` in a form, only the person table record is OK. But the **function_id** attribute in the `participant` table is **NULL**. What is necessary to set only the value **function_id** in the `participant` table when the user creates a person? So when a new person is created a participant should be created always.

There are **4** tables:

- trial `has_many :participants`
- participant `belongs_to` person
- person `has_many participants`... `has_many` :trials, through: participants
- function `has_many` participants

What works so far:

Creating a new participant (id | trial_id | **function_id** | person_id) with a form `/views/participants/new.html.erb` works. Creating a new person (id | title | prename | surname etc.) with a form `/views/persons/new.html.erb` works not 100% like mentiond above.
In the form `persons/new.html.erb` the user should be able to select an option in a dropdown box which is the function of a `participant`.

I don't want a completly new `participant` record. I want only the **function_id** value.

Below is a snippet of the `/persons/views/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for([@trial, @person]) do |f| %>
<div class="table">
<fieldset>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">
        <%= f.label t(:function) %>
      </div>
      <div class="tdsep">:</div>
      <div class="td">
       <%= f.select :function_id, Function.all.collect {|fu| [fu.german, fu.id]}  %>
     </div>
    </div>
   ...
```

**EDIT**

Person model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  attr_accessible :organization_id,:title,:prename,:surname,:street,:street_number,:zip_code,:city,:phone,:fax,:email,:organization_description, :participants_attributes
  has_many :participants
  has_many :trials, through: :participants
```

PersonsController

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController

 load_and_authorize_resource :person, :through => :trial, :only => [:destroy]
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :new, :create, :show]
 load_and_authorize_resource :trial

 def new
  @person = Person.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @person}
  end
end

def create
  @person = Person.new(params[:person])
  @person.trials << @trial
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @person, status: :created, location: @person }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `belongs_to :function` to your person model.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. There is still `undefined method function_id' for #<Person:0x9bbe9c4>`. Should I adjust the view, too?

Comment: Can you edit your post with your person model and the params get by your controller ?

Comment: Add ```belongs_to :function``` to person model and ```function_id``` to attr_accessible

Comment: If I do so `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` appears. The `function_id` is part of the participant table btw. Edit: hat a typo in controller. But still the error above appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `function_id` in your person new view because there isn't any `function_id`in the person db.

So the solution is to make a `select_tag` instead of `f.select`.

```
 <%= select_tag :function_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Function.all.collect {|fu| [fu.german, fu.id]})  %>
```

See [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for more informations

Comment: I did it. And now the error `ArgumentError in Persons#new - wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)`appears. I am just reading your recommended source. But what are the other 2 parameters?

Comment: what is your rails version ?

Comment: My rails version is 3.2.13

Comment: try ```select_tag('function_id', options_from_collection_for_select(Function.all.collect {|fu| [fu.german, fu.id]}, {})```

Comment: Now there is `wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)`.^^ I think there is also missing an ending bracket. I added it so it's `,{}))`

Comment: ```select_tag('function_id', options_from_collection_for_select(Function.all.collect {|fu| [fu.german, fu.id]}), {})```

Comment: Now it is again `ArgumentError in Persons#new - wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)`. I copy pasted your code...

Comment: Do you think it is even possible to save the `function_id`  through a `person` form even though `function_id` is not an persons' attribute?